# How to create a hideable bottom view

Tags: xamarin.forms, slider, controls, audio-streaming, drawer

I've developed a **Xamarin.Forms.Shell app** containing 4 tabs.

I would like to add a **basic audio player** allowing to play music from a streaming source.

But I'm looking to the best way to manage it:

- I don't want to display it in a dedicated page, as I don't get the metadata of the audio (no album photo, no title, no author, ...) and there are no "Play Next" or "Play Previous" features
- I would like to display a basic view appearing at the bottom and above of the main page, containing 3 buttons (play or pause/stop/close) and the name of the radio

I would like to do something like this:
[image: App sample]

But I don't know what is the better approach to achieve this:

- use a **Drawer** like [SimpleBottomDrawer](https://github.com/galadril/Xam.Plugin.SimpleBottomDrawer)
- use a **Slide** like [SlideOverKit](https://github.com/XAM-Consulting/SlideOverKit)
- use a **Sheet** like [BottomSheet](https://github.com/rlingineni/Forms-BottomSheet)

All of these solution seem too complicated for my needs.

***Is there another approach?***

Comment: "All of these solution seem too complicated" probably because what you are trying to achieve is in fact complicated. Have you tried them? what doesn't fit your requirement in the 3 approach you have mentioned ?

Comment: Maybe yes... It seemed not complicated to hide/show a view at the bottom of the screen, but I didn't found a simple way to achieve it. That's why I preferred to ask: maybe someone has already did it or could have an idea...

Comment: The idea of the bottom tabs is that it must be a simple way for the users to access different sections of your app easily. They are working natively on each platform, so if you want to hide them you must get your hands dirty with custom renderers, or you can try to implement it on xamarin forms, but you would have to make the navigation your self on each button click.

Comment: @FabriBertani the question focus on a collapsable/hideable view above the bottom tabs, not the bottom tabs themselves. Gold.strike Will one of the 3 repo works for you? (a part from the complexity point of view). you want something complicated must be a solution with the same complexity. You can start implementing one and if you have issues post specific ones.

Comment: I've finally implemented a basic / simple solution, by using Frame and transition.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution I've implemented.

By default, I display a **Floating Action Button**, that will show the **radio player control panel**.

In this panel, I have the **"play"/"stop" controls**, the radio **title**, and a **"close" button** to hide the panel.

The **radio player control panel** is hidden by default by applying a  `TranslationY`

The **XAML** looks like this:

```
<Grid>
    <!-- FloatingActionButton -->
    <yummy:PancakeView x:Name="RadioFab"
                CornerRadius="28"                       
                Padding="16"
                BackgroundColor="{StaticResource AccentColor}"
                VerticalOptions="End"
                HorizontalOptions="End"
                Margin="25">
        <yummy:PancakeView.Shadow>
            <yummy:DropShadow Offset="1,2"
                              Color="{StaticResource Gray-Black}"
                              BlurRadius="2"
                              Opacity="0.2"/>
        </yummy:PancakeView.Shadow>
        <Image HeightRequest="24" WidthRequest="24">
            <Image.Source ... />
        </Image>
        <yummy:PancakeView.GestureRecognizers>
            <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="RadioFab_Clicked" />
        </yummy:PancakeView.GestureRecognizers>
    </yummy:PancakeView>
    <!-- Radio player view
    <yummy:PancakeView x:Name="RadioPlayerView"
                       VerticalOptions="End"
                       HeightRequest="56"
                       BackgroundColor="{StaticResource Gray-400}"
                       Opacity="0.9"
                       TranslationY="56"
                       IsVisible="True">
       <!-- content ... -->
    </yummy:PancakeView>
<Grid>
```

When the **Floating Action Button** is clicked, I call the `TranslateTo()` method, allowing me to display the panel, and to get the expected behaviour.

The **code-behind** looks like this:

```
private void RadioFab_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.RadioFab.ScaleTo(0, easing: Easing.Linear);
    this.RadioPlayerView.TranslateTo(0, 0, 300);
}

void Player_CloseButton_Clicked(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    this.RadioPlayerView.TranslateTo(0, 56, 300);
    this.RadioFab.ScaleTo(1, easing: Easing.SpringOut);
}
```